# Django 1.8.2 - display dictionary of dictionary in template

Tags: python, django, templates, dictionary, django-1.8

I am using Django 1.8.2 and I am having some trouble figuring out how to iterate over this complex dictionary.  I am trying to pass this information onto my template and display the information.

```
context = {'name': 'John', 'inventory': '[{"hardware": "Desktop", "brand": "HP"}, {"hardware": "Server" "brand": "Dell"}]'}
```

Any ideas?  Much appreciated.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: There are errors in your dict, additional quotes before list and comma missing.

Answer (score 0):

In your template :

```
{{ name }}
{% for item in inventory %}
  {{ item.hardware }}
  {{ item.brand }}
{% endfor %}
```

And read this documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/

Answer (score 0):

> Check your dictionary and make it like this,

```
context = {'name': 'John', 'inventory': '[{"hardware": "Desktop", "brand": "HP"}, {"hardware": "Server", "brand": "Dell"}]'}
```

and in template

```
{{ name }}
{% for item in inventory %}
  {{ item.hardware }}
  {{ item.brand }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Template**

```
{{ name }}
{% for item in inventory %}
    {{ item.hardware }}
    {{ item.brand }}
{% endfor %}
```

**View**

You cannot iterate a string (besides iterating each character).
Instead, you will have to either pass a dict (if your data source is JSON) or an array of model (database).

In your example:

```
import simplejson
inventory_dict = simplejson.loads('{"inventory": [{"hardware": "Desktop", "brand": "HP"}, {"hardware": "Server", "brand": "Dell"}]}')
context = {'name': 'John', }
context.update(inventory_dict)
```

Comment: `try: import simplejson as json`    
`except ImportError: import json`